# System of differential equations without solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, systems-of-equations

Analyzing the certain problem in differential geometry, I obtained the following system of differential equations
$$6f'(u)g'(u)-gf''(u)-fg''(u)=0,$$
$$-3g(u)f'(u)^2+3f(u)f'(u)g'(u)+f(u)g(u)f''(u)-g''(u)-f(u)^2g''(u)=0,$$
$$-3f'(u)^2+3g'(u)^2+f(u)f''(u)-g(u)g''(u)=0,$$
$$3g(u)f'(u)g'(u)-3f(u)g'(u)^2-f''(u)-g(u)^2f''(u)+f(u)g(u)g''(u)=0.$$
From geometry point of view, only solution should be constant functions, but are there any arguments from theory of differential equations which can confirm my thoughts.

Comment: You system is quite overdetermined. You can solve the first two equations for $f''$ and $g''$, in general the solutions will not satisfy the other equations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I believe it would be the argument why there is no solutions,other than constant functions. Can you please explain me, what would be the method for obtaining f'' and g'', just few hints and I will try to solve  it by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Put your system in a more systematic form
$$
\pmatrix{g&f\\-fg&1+f^2\\-f&g\\1+g^2&-fg}
\pmatrix{f''\\g''}
=
\pmatrix{6f'g'\\-3gf'^2+3ff'g'\\−3f'^2+3g'^2\\3gf'g'−3fg'^2}
$$

The first and third equations can be combined to
$$
\pmatrix{f&-g\\g&f}\pmatrix{f''\\g''}=3\pmatrix{f'^2-g'^2\\2f'g'}
\\\text{or}\\
(f+ig)(f''+ig'')=3(f'+ig')^2
$$
implying by integrating once $$f'+ig'=C(f+ig)^3\tag{*},$$ and twice
$$
(f+ig)^{-2}=D-Cu\implies f^2+g^2=|D-Cu|^{-1}.
$$

Now combine the 4th and 2nd equation to get similar second derivative terms like the first set of equations, $f(IV)+g(II)$ gives
$$
ff''+gg''=-3(f^2g'^2-2ff'gg'+f'^2g^2)=-3(fg'-f'g)^2=-3Im((f-ig)(f'+ig'))^2
$$
But also 
$$
ff''+gg''=Re((f-ig)(f''+ig''))=3\frac{Re\Bigl((f-ig)(f'+ig'))^2\Bigr)}{f^2+g^2}
$$
Now insert the above first-order differential equation (*) to get to the identity
$$
-Im(C(f^2+g^2)(f+ig)^2)^2=\frac{Re\Bigl((C(f^2+g^2)(f+ig)^2)^2\Bigr)}{f^2+g^2}
\\\iff\\
-(f^2+g^2)\,Im(C(f+ig)^2)^2=Re(C^2(f+ig)^4)=Re(C(f+ig)^2)^2-Im(C(f+ig)^2)^2
\\\iff\\
(1-|Cu-D|^{-1})\,Im(C(Cu-D))^2=Re(C(Cu-D))^2
\\\iff\\
-Im(C(Cu-D))^2=|Cu-D|\cdot Re(C^2(Cu-D)^2).
$$

This last should be impossible for $C\ne 0$, starting from the degree inequality giving $Re(C^4)=0$, $Re(C^3D)=0$ etc. Note that there is still a combination of the 2nd and 4th equation open for further restrictions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you are very kind.

Comment: Again, I have problem understanding why is the last expression impossible for $C \neq 0.$ It would be clear if $C$ is a real number, but it is complex. Or not?

Comment: The last equation essentially sets two different rational expressions in $u$ equal. I find it highly unlikely that, after transforming it into a polynomial equation, the coefficients of equal degrees can all be equal simultaneously over all degrees. For $C=0$ the last identity becomes trivial, and equation (*) gives that $f,g$ are constant in $u$.